# Getting distinct values from a list of objects with objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class which has two objects with in it.
For example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Carnivorous MeatEater { get; set; }
    public Herbivorous VegEater { get; set; }
    public Animal()
    {           
        this.MeatEater = new Carnivorous();
        this.VegEater = new Herbivorous();
    }
}
```

`Carnivorous` and `Herbivorous` have a `Category` property.

I populated this class with a list of data from my database which is stored in either `MeatEater` or `VegEater`. 
I need to get a distinct list of `Category` from both and `MeatEater` and `VegEater` combined.
How can I get this list?

Thanks!

Comment: how you define your `Category` class?

Comment: ...huh. I kinda thought animals "were" meat eaters or veg eaters, rather than "having" meat eaters or veg eaters. This organization feels difficult to wrap my head around; I'd expect MeatEater to be an interface.

Comment: Just to make sure, this list will contain only 0 (no MeatEater or VegEater object present), 1 (either only MeatEater *or* VegEater has been assigned, or they both have the same category), or 2 distinct categories will be returned here, right? There's no hidden information that "carnivorous" is a list or something?

Comment: Sorry, If i am not clear.

Comment: Sorry, If i am not clear.  Based on the data validation, i store in meateater or vegeater. for eg. meateater has 2 records: "Trex", a description, "Very Large" (category) & "Lion", a desc, "Medium".
veg eater has 2 records: "Cow", a desc, "Medium" and "Lamb", a desc, "Small".

I have to get a distinct list with "large", "Medium" and "Small".
Hope I am Clear now.

Comment: Are you using the Animal class like a table that has MeatEaters and VegEaters? Your confusion might a side effect of this incorrect approach. This class should only represent ONE instance of an Animal that contains a property that describes if its a MeatEater or VegEater. Then from a list of animals, you could get a distinct list from that. Currently your class composition makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, here you go: (this is assuming `Category` is a `string`, else you also have to overload `Equals` in your categories class):

```
var result = myList.SelectMany(GetValidCategories).Where(s => s != null)
                   .Distinct();
```

A needed function:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetValidCategories(Animal a)
{
    List<string> categories = new List<string>();
    if (a.MeatEater != null) categories.Add(a.MeatEater.Category);
    if (a.VegEater != null) categories.Add(a.VegEater.Catergory);
    return categories;
}
```

HOWEVER, this is not a good design. Animals are meat and/or veg eaters. They do not have them.

A better design would be this:

```
[Flags] public enum AnimalType { Carnivorous = 1, Herbivorous = 2, Ominovorous = 3 }
public class Animal
{
    public AnimalType Type { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    //all the other members that Herbivorous + Carnivorous share,
    //so pretty much all of them really.
}
```

Then, it would be much easier:

```
var result = myList.Select(a => a.Category).Where(s => s != null).Distinct();
```

Comment: Omnivores would like a word with your assumption. :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice `[Flags]` would like to have a word with **yours**. :P

Comment: I meant, your line "Animals are meat or veg eaters"...  surely "and/or" is better... as they can be both :)

Comment: Actually, extending it..  using your `Flags` solution..  `enum AnimalType { Carnivorous = 1, Herbivorous = 2, Ominovorous = 3 }`.  Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

At least one basic approach is to first select them indpendently then union.

```
using System.Linq;

var query1 = (from animal in myList
    select animal.MeatEater.Category).Distinct();

var query2 = (from animal in myList
    select animal.VegEater.Category).Distinct();

var result = query1.Union(query2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the categories from meat eaters to a list and all the categories from veg eaters to the same list if the category is not already present.

```
var lstCategories = new List<string>();

foreach(string category in animal.MeatEater.Category)
    if(!lstCategories.Contains(category))
        lstCategories.add(category);

foreach(string category in animal.VegEater.Category)
    if(!lstCategories.Contains(category))
        lstCategories.add(category);
```

so finally the lstCategories will have distinct set of combined Categories at the end.